# d3 topojson zoom on map with cities

Tags: d3.js, plot, zooming, topojson

I'm working on a d3 map with topojson format data.
I can draw the country shapes and the zoom and pane works fine.

The problem is when I try to plot cities on the map.
I can not figure out how to manage the zoom with those points: the point size must be the same, but the points must translate right.

this is an example, when I zoom the map, the points translate out of the map:

```
    var width = 724;
var height = 768;
var objMap = null;

var x, y;

//Projection
projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator()
    .center([2.5, -38.5])
    .rotate([66, 0])
    .scale((height * 56.5) / 33)
    .translate([(width / 2), (height / 2)]);    

//Path
path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, width])
    .range([0, width]);

y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);        

svg = d3.select("#div_map").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);        

g = svg.append("g");        

// Zoom behavior
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()               
    .scaleExtent([1,15])
    .on("zoom",function() {     

        g.selectAll("path.zoomable").attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")")   
        g.selectAll(".place").attr("transform", function(d) { p = projection(d.geometry.coordinates); return "translate(" + x(p[0]) + "," + y(p[1]) + ")"; });                                      
    }
);
svg.call(zoom);

d3.json("datos/ARcompleto.json.txt", function (error, ar) {

    objMap = ar;

    //Draw the map
    provs = g.append("g")
    .attr("id", "g_provincias")
    .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(ar, ar.objects.provincias).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .classed("zoomable", true)
        .attr("d", path)            

    g.append("g")   
        .attr("id", "g_localidades")                                
        .selectAll("path")                                                              
        .data(topojson.feature(objMap, objMap.objects.localidades).features.filter(function (d) { return d.properties.LPROVINCIA == 'MENDOZA'; }))
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("d", path)                                    
            .attr("class", "localidad")
            .classed("place", true)
            //.attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates.reverse()) + ")"; });

});
```

Comment: You're using two different methods for the zoom/pan. Try setting `transform` on the locations in a similar way as you're doing for the paths.

Comment: Lars thanks for your reply. It tried with: g.selectAll(".place").attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.translate.join(",")+")"), but it does not work.

Comment: You would also need to `scale` the places.

Comment: But my idea is not scale the places. I want to do something like google maps, where if you zoom the map the markers keep their size

Comment: You will need to scale them to get the coordinates right. What are the places? If they're circles, you can simply adjust `r` according to the zoom level.

Comment: They are paths. If I put: g.selectAll(".place").attr("transform","translate("+d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")"); The places translate well but scale equal to subdivisions map, and this not what I want

Comment: It sounds like you would need different paths for different zoom levels. Certainly with your current setup you can't do what you want easily because you would need to change the way the paths are projected/drawn.

Comment: Lars, thank a lot for your help. Do you know where found an example? I was looking for in but can not found any.

Comment: I'm not aware of any example -- as I've said, it sounds like you would need different data for the different zoom levels. Alternatively, you could mark the locations with e.g. circles at their center and scale the radius of the circles according to the zoom level.

Comment: Lars, thanks a million for your help. I could manage it using another zoom function:     var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .translate(projection.translate())
  .scaleExtent([height, Infinity])
  .scale(projection.scale())
  .on("zoom", function() {
   projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)
   g.selectAll("path.zoomable").attr("d", path);
   
   projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)
   svg.selectAll(".place").attr("d", path);   
   
 });

Answer (score 0):

I can manage it with the Lars help. this is the new zoom function:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scaleExtent([height, Infinity])
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .on("zoom", function() {
        projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)
        g.selectAll("path.zoomable").attr("d", path);

        projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale)
        svg.selectAll(".place").attr("d", path);    

});
```

Thanks a lot!